# удержание ссылки от очистки arc

Tags: ios, objective-c

Подскажите, пожалуйста.
Есть некоторое свойство класса static void * someProperty. Я его определил в одном методе класса и мне нужно к нему обратится через минут 5-10 (в течении этого времени приложение активно и не свернуто, но не используется). Как я могу удержать ссылку, чтобы arc не почистил его? Спасибо

Comment: Добавьте код. Как Вы объявляете `someProperty`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если речь идёт о свойстве класса в Objective-C (class property со статической переменной в имплементации, например), то ARC и не станет его удалять, поскольку указатель на объект будет лежать в статической памяти. Написать это можно так (на примере синглтона):

В .h-файле:

```
@property (class, nonatomic, readonly) MyObject *sharedInstance;
```

В .m-файле:

```
+ (MyObject *)sharedInstance
{
  static MyObject *singleton;
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    singleton = [MyObject new];
  });
  return singleton;
}
```